# Would creating a Q&A question to cover specific 14.04 sound issues be okay here?

Tags: discussion, faq-suggestion

I was looking at the numerous cases in a search of people having sound issues, especially with 14.04, and I was wondering if I could create a little Q&A FAQ (community wiki) about it?

Many of [these questions](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=no+sound+%5B14.04%5D) happens to be variations of a common complaint about an [ALSA bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1320020) I've filed, where these are the symptoms:

1. Speakers intermittently work, with no apparent pattern.
2. Headphones always work.
3. Re-installing anything has no effect.
4. Re-configuring PulseAudio has no effect, regardless of configuration.

Another common one is broken sound under Realtek cards, where this is a known bug with a known workaround (link will be found).

I have a few lists of question links that I will point to this Q&A, followed by others as I find them.

List of possible bug issues so far:

- https://askubuntu.com/q/466627 (I already have a pointer to the relevant bug)

  - https://askubuntu.com/a/466627/258567 (accepted answer of mine, helpful addition)
- [audio driver not supported in linux 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/470597)
- [lost sound ubuntu 14.04, tried everything](https://askubuntu.com/q/493073)
- [No sound devices or input devices (Ubuntu 14)](https://askubuntu.com/q/500934)

Realtek hardware issue:

- [No sound, dummy output, realtek ac880, ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/507202)
- [Lubuntu 14.04 - No soundcard detected HDA Intel Realtek ALC880](https://askubuntu.com/q/462655)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Broad general sound issues Q&A? Don't see it as a good thing.

Normally attempts for that just result in big fails that are not maintained or do not reflect current status of the situation when evaluated after some time.

If you are simply going to describe a bug then just leave it and point the question you see relevant to its launchpad page.

If its a specific matter or issue that you can cover as a "how to" that will not change next week then you are more than welcomed to do so.

Comment: I've seen about 10 questions in an hour of searching that are not detailed enough that I can mark them as dupes of anything, but they are variations of the same bug I've reported. Any suggestions on handling this?

Comment: Is it a bug? Close them as a bug? Are you sure its the same thing? Bug?

Comment: Yes. I just wanted to know how to handle it other than this route.

Comment: I just flagged all of the first list.

Comment: In this specific case **I disagree that this is a bug**. If an incomplete shutdown of Windows messes up our sound system there is little we can (and should) do from Ubuntu. The posts mentioned should therefore be closed as a **dupe**, not as off topic for being a bug. We can argue to close them as off topic for not being related to Ubuntu but in case we have an answer with an easy solution closing as dupe will help users more.

Comment: @Takkat but ofc course, but I do not see how your point fits all the posts there. And closed as a dupe of what?

Comment: This may be a question with a good answer we can link to in case the issue is related to Windows hibernating: http://askubuntu.com/questions/464388/no-sound-from-laptop-speakers-in-ubuntu-14-04-after-booting-into-windows-8-1

Comment: The problem is, we cant really say that **all** of the questions mentioned here are really the same issue.

Comment: @Takkat I agree

Answer (score 0):

That's why tags were invented. Let's use it wisely!